# JPA OneToMany list is always empty

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa, one-to-many

I'm working on a JPA project, and i had an issue with OneToMany relationship.
I have Member class which extends Person Class(@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) and I have Baby Class which extends Person too.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected int id;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    ...

@Entity   
public class Member extends Person{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", targetEntity =       Baby.class)
    private Set<Baby> babies;
    ....

 @Entity
 public class Baby extends Person{
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Member parent;
    ....
```

In baby side there is no problem but babies Set in Member class is always empty!!

this is a replay to some comments:

Yes Mateus Viccari, I checked and the parent_id is the good one
Here is my complet code:

```
@Entity
public class Member extends Person implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID =      -2683015788944585661L;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Baby> babies;   

public Member(String name, String firstName, String address, String numTel, String email, Date birthDay){
        super(name, firstName, address, numTel, email, birthDay);
}

Member(){
    super(null, null, null, null, null, null);
}


public Set<Baby> getBabies(){
    return babies;
}
public void setBabies(Set<Baby> babies){
    this.babies = babies;
}

}

@Entity
public class Baby extends Person implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7044695859030235095L;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Member parent;

    public Baby(String name, String firstName, String address, String numTel,
        String email, Date birthDay, Member parent){
    super(name, firstName, address, numTel, email, birthDay);
    this.parent = parent;
}

Baby(){
    super(null, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public Member getParent(){
    return parent;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Baby [parent=" + parent + ", toString()=" + super.toString()
            + "]";
}

}
```

This is how I do to retrieve members list:

```
Member parent = new Member("Aslami", "Khalid", "test", null, null, Date.valueOf("1974-04-15"));
Baby b = new Baby("Aslami", "Rayan", "test", null, null, Date.valueOf("2012-12-24"), parent);
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM Baby b").executeUpdate();
em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM Member m").executeUpdate();
em.merge(b);
em.getTransaction().commit();
List<Baby> babies = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT b FROM Baby b").getResultList();
List<Member> members = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT m FROM Member m").getResultList();
assertEquals(1, babies.size());
assertEquals("Aslami", babies.get(0).getName());
assertEquals(1, members.get(0).getBabies().size());
```

Comment: It's empty when doing what?

Comment: When selecting a member who has children in the database

Comment: In JPA it;s the programmer's responsibility to take care of the runtime relationships between the entities

Comment: So what is the utility of this annotation if it can't retrieve the referenced items?!

Comment: You have to show us more of your code, not just the fields, after all we are not magicians. This might be helpful http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=55191

Comment: Your classes look correct.  Can you include an example of the code you're using to retrieve the entities?

Comment: Look at the question, I added the classes code

Comment: try adding the baby to the parent set before persisting to db

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in your database if the "Babies" have the correct parent_id?

Comment: Yes Mateus Viccari, I checked and the parent_id is the good one.
I added supplement code in the question